# FAST 2010 Search and SharePoint 2010 Search - Advanced Search, Date Properties

Tags: fast-search

I have a SharePoint Site Collection with regional settings changed to dd/mm/yyyy overall, all date picker controls change and I get the dd/mm/yyyy format.

I have an Enterprise Search Center in which we have the Advanced Search, where one can search for all content based on Created or Modified Date.

Now, this continues to only take mm/dd/yyyy format of dates inspite of that site's regional settings being changed to dd/mm as well.

How do we change this and make all the date parameters in the Advanced Search work on dd/mm/yyyy?

Answer (score 1):

I have/had a PSS case open regarding this. I'll need to check but I believe the problem is with FAST and it doesn't actually support different regions properly. You can see this if you navigate to the "Create User Context" from the site settings page.

If your region is en-US then the buttons have labels, if your region is en-GB then the buttons don't.

I'll come back later after I've searched my emails.

Comment: Confirmed. I have a PSS case open, and it was accepted as a bug by R&D. This problem is due to be resolved in FAST4SharePoint SP1. I don't have that signed in blood, but that's coming from a conversation I had with a PSS engineer.

Answer (score 0):

Search Center is usually a site on its own you should be able to change the regional setting for the search center site.

Comment: I have done that Renzo, but no difference. Ofcourse within the results, the date that appears comes correctly in dd/mm format, but the Advanced Search Created / Modified properties based date format - takes only mm/dd